# Would this be the full list of materials to connect a ML8511 UV sensor to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, sensor, wiring, breadboard

I have the [SparkFun ML8511/UV Sensor Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12705).

In order to connect this to a Raspberry Pi would I need any other materials besides the following:

1. A Breadboard
2. A MCP3008 for analogue to digital conversion.
3. Some Male - Male and Male - Female Breadboard Wires.
4. Raspberry Pi 3 B
5. The sensor itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also need pin headers, solder, and a soldering iron to connect the pin headers to the breakout board.

In addition you will need a bootable SD card for the Pi3B.

Apart from those provisos your list looks complete.

Comment: What about the pis power supply

Comment: @MohammadAli Yes, indeed.   ...and a microUSB lead, and a power outlet, and an electrical grid transmission network, and a power station, and coal.  You have to stop somewhere.

Comment: I mean you could simply stop at uranium. I get your point in all, but I know some people that have bought the Pi Thinking that a power supply was included.

Comment: @MohammadAli Fair enough.